# Powershell print the content of pipes?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following script.

```
Get-Job | ? { $_.State -eq 'Completed' } | Remove-Job
```

I want to display the removed jobs in one chained pipes. The following script doesn't work.

```
 Get-Job | ? { $_.State -eq 'Completed' } | Remove-Job | % { echo "Removed: $_" }
```

And the following get errors.

```
 Get-Job | ? { $_.State -eq 'Completed' } | % { echo "Removed: $_" } | Remove-Job
```

> Remove-Job : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
>   the command either because t he command does not take pipeline input
>   or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters
>   that take pipeline input. At line:2 char:81
>   + Get-Job | ? { $*.State -eq 'Completed' } | % { echo "Removed: $*" } | Remove-Job <<<< 
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Removed: System...n.PSRemotingJob:PSObject) [Re     move-Job],
>   ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveJobComman
>   d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like this to keep it simple:

```
get-job | ?{$_.state -eq "Completed"} | 
  %{ Remove-Job $_; Write-host "Removed $($_.Name)" }
```

For what you were trying to work, you have to do:

```
get-job | ?{$_.state -eq "Completed"}  | %{write-host "Removed: $($_.Name)"; $_} | 
   Remove-Job
```

Note the `$_`, passing the job back to the pipeline.

Comment: A number of Remove- cmdlets have a -PassThru to make life easier, and let you avoid this sort of code.  Unfortunately, Remove-Job isn't one of them.

Comment: @Start-Automating - I am thinking why a Remove cmdlet would have passthru?

Comment: @manojlds... for reasons like this.  You might say, remove an item from a collection, but want that item returned.   Out of the box I see two:

Get-Command -Verb Remove | Where-Object { $_.Parameters.PassThru }

One makes sense to me (Remove-Computer - passing along the list of the computer names).  There other makes a lot less sense to me (removing snapins).

There are many situations where Remove is dangerous from a memory perspective, because the object reference could be disposed, or because seeing the removed object could be a "HeisenBug".